# Why is the sigmoid function interpreted as a saturating firing rate of a neuron?

Tags: artificial-neuron, neurons, sigmoid

I've seen several people say that sigmoids are like a saturating firing rate of a neuron but I don't see how or why they interpret it as such. I especially don't see the relationship between a "rate" (so a number of something over time, I guess here it's the number that a neuron activates in a unit of time) and the sigmoid graph. For me it resembles more to the voltage output of an operational amplifier in some cases.

Comment: Sigmoid outputs a value between 0-1, this can be interpreted as the probability of the neuron ‘firing’.

Comment: @DavidIreland that could be an interpretation. Like the probability of a neuron "firing" when the input is x is $\sigma (x)$ (where $\sigma$ denotes the sigmoid function).

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide 1-2 references where people say "sigmoids are like a saturating firing rate of a neuron", just to have more context.

Comment: @nbro You're right, sorry for this imprecision. So a friend of mine told me about this interpretation (it was given by his professor and he found it cool) and when I searched for it I found this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14349/difference-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-in-general I agree it's not many people I just thought that since it's a professor who said it, he maybe have read/heard it somewhere else etc... ^^'